# How to import all sheets of excel workbook to Access with VBA.

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been given an excel file with `1429 sheets`. I need to get all the data into Access 2013, either as one table or several, and am looking for a `VBA` method (or anything else that will work).

The code given in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21787353/10176204) does not work for me though it seems to have been working for others a few years ago:

> "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

In reference to line "For lngCount = 1 To objWorkbook.Worksheets.Count"

Comment: That code is going to generate 1429 tables in your Access database. I just can't imagine that being a good idea. Perhaps it's a start though. You use that code (put `Sub transferworkbook()` at the top of the code and `end sub` at the bottom and try again) then once everything is transfered write up a UNION query to stitch it all together. I wouldn't anticipate this to be an easy job as there will be no magic bullet.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was running it in a sub but had it in the wrong place. Edited to explain new problem.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting that error. Did you change that strPathFile variable to point to your workbook? Does the workbook open when the code hits that previous line?

Comment: Could we see the exact code you've used - edited into your question please?  That line of code runs fine when I try it, but that [error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/object-variable-not-set-error-91) can appear to occur on a certain line while the actual error is caused elsewhere (such as an `End With` being missed).

Comment: Add `objExcel.Visible = True` after an instance of Excel has been created - is a workbook open when the error occurs?

Comment: You need to adapt that code. Please read: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it in the end and it turned out to be something really dumb: the code worked after I converted the source spreadsheet to .xlsx format. I ended up using the second code posted in the [same answer I linked to before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21787353/10176204) which imports all the spreadsheets to a single table.

Thank you for all your help, I learned a lot here!