# Import multiple sheets from workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I've adapted this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784089/how-to-import-one-excel-file-that-contain-multiple-worksheets-into-an-access-tab) to import multiple Excel sheets into multiple tables using VBA in Access from a single Excel file.

It creates the new tables, names them correctly, uses the range specified, closes the workbook after....
***but each new Access table has the same contents (from worksheet 1)!***

ie NewTable1 and NewTable2 both contain contents of Worksheet1 despite having different names. It seems like the code is working so I don't know why this error keeps happening. Any help is appreciated.

My edited code, adapted from linked post:

```
Function ImportData()
   ' Requires reference to Microsoft Office 11.0 Object Library.
   Dim fDialog As FileDialog
   Dim varFile As Variant

   ' Clear listbox contents.
   'Me.FileList.RowSource = ""

   ' Set up the File Dialog.
   Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(3)

   With fDialog

      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Filters.Add "Excel File", "*.xlsx"
    .Filters.Add "Excel File", "*.xls"

      If .Show = True Then

         'Loop through each file selected and add it to our list box.
         For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
         ' Label3.Caption = varFile

         Const acImport = 0
         Const acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml = 10

         ''This gets the sheets to new tables
         GetSheets varFile

         Next
         MsgBox ("Import data successful!")
         End If
End With
End Function


Function GetSheets(strFileName)
    'Requires reference to the Microsoft Excel x.x Object Library

    Dim objXL As New Excel.Application
    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks As Object

    'objXL.Visible = True

    Set wkb = objXL.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)

    For Each wks In wkb.Worksheets
        'MsgBox wks.Name
        Set TableName = wks.Cells(10, "B")
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
        TableName, strFileName, True, "14:150"
    Next

   'Tidy up
   objXL.DisplayAlerts = False
   wkb.Close
   Set wkb = Nothing
   objXL.Quit
   Set objXL = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet just pulls from first worksheet unless specify otherwise. Instead of `"14:150"`, use:

`wks.Name & "$14:150"`

or

`wks.Name & "!14:150"`

Or use wks.CodeName to pull the sheet index instead of name in case there are issues with name construct.

Without a range reference, the $ character would be needed.

Comment: transferspreadsheet doesn't seem to pull from the active sheet.  adding wks.activate to the top of getsheets doesn't fix the error.  Instead it seems to default to the first sheet in the workbook.

Comment: I didn't suggest adding wks.activate. Suggestion I did make worked for me.

Comment: comment should have read docmd.transferspreadsheet seems to pull from first worksheet by default because calling wks.activate to change the active worksheet doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Oh, got it, revised answer.

Comment: Thanks for the troubleshooting.

Unfortunately, adding:

`wks.Name & "$"`

to the [range] field resulted in 

Run-time error '3125': '[WorksheetName]$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

possibly because the sheets I'm working with have max characters in each tab.

Could you explain what the function of the $ character is? I'm a novice with VBA.

Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but I do not think this solution will output the range I wanted (14:150). Do you know how to incorporate this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why does your error message show [ ] characters? Is sheet actually named "WorksheetName"? `wks.name & "$14:150"` works for me. So does `wks.name & "!14:150"`. Without the range reference, have to use $.

Comment: when I replicated the problem June's solution worked for me.

Comment: I used the square bracketed generic name to simplify - sorry for the confusion. The error was Run-time error '3105': ' Testosterone decanoate_METHOXY$' is not a valid name... I have tried the above but for some reason I get the same error. i.e. ' Testosterone decanoate_METHOXY$14:150' is not a valid name... I also tested if it was a sheet name length issue, but again, ' Testosterone decanoate$14:150' is not a valid name... Do you have any other ideas mazoula and @June7 ?

Comment: Maybe don't use space in sheet name.

Comment: Solved. It fails to read a sheet name that begins with a space. Spacing mid-way or after the name doesn't fail. I can't believe this was the problem haha. Thank you a tonne for your help. The method for generating the sheets names in software just needs to be fixed so that it doesn't exceed the character limit and cause chopped up sheet names.

Comment: Apparently using `wks.CodeName` instead of `wks.Name` also works, because the sheet is referenced by sheet index rather than the space-led sheet name.

Comment: Nice to know. Added that info to my answer. Why does sheet name begin with a space?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use a string variable like

```
 Dim strRange as string

 strRange = "sheetname!14:150"
```

and then

```
 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
    TableName, strFileName, True, stRrange
```

Comment: Thanks Junkie. Unfortunately I encountered errors when applying this solution. If implemented exactly:

`Set Range = wks.Range("14:150")` and `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, TableName, strFileName, True, Range` 
I would get "Compile error: Argument not optional". If I instead tried:
`WksRange = wks.Range("14:150")` and `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, TableName, strFileName, True, WksRange` 
I get "Run-time error '2498': An expression you entered is the wrong data type for one of the arguments". Any ideas?

Comment: found the bug and edited my solution. Hope that does the trick for you now

Comment: ...and spaces in the sheet name should not be an issue. Just put it in the string exactly as it is in the tab. I tried my solution in a quick test, and it worked fine (without spaces though :-) )